# bulma calendar component in angular not getting displayed

Tags: angular

I am trying to import the bulma calendar component in my angular 7 project.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bulma-calendar

I have installed the component in my component using

npm i bulma-calendar

What is the syntax for importing this in my component.

When i try

```
import {bulma-calendar} from "@bulma-calendar/bulma-calendar"
```

I get a red squiggly all over the import statement in angular.

What i am seeing in the html template is nothing but a ordinary HTML5 date picker component any ideas what i am doing wrong ?

```
<div id="range" class="tab-content is-active">
    <div class="tab-content is-active">
        <input id="datepickerDemoInlineRange" class="input" data-display-mode="inline" data-is-range="true" type="date">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the error you are facing?

Comment: When i try to import import {bulma-calendar} from "@bulma-calendar/bulma-calendar" i get a red squiggly all over in VS Code.Sorry should have mentioned this in my question

Comment: may be you need typed defination for the same